# Overriding inline !important CSS with Javscript code snippet with media query

Tags: plugins, css, javascript, jquery, html

There's a piece of inline CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css" id="illdy-about-section-css">
#header.header-front-page {background-image: url(image.png) !important;}
#header.header-front-page {background-position-y: center;}
#header.header-front-page {background-position-x: center;}
#header.header-front-page {background-size: auto !important;}
```

on a Wordpress theme/site homepage, and I want to get the 'background-size' to "100%" with or without the "!important".

I have a plugin called [Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) that's supposed to enable PHP without messing with source files, and I used:

```
<?php
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_front_page ()) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1'>
          // your javascript code goes here
            
            $('#header.header-front-page').css('background-size', '')
            $('#header.header-front-page').css('background-size', '100%!important')


        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

But nothing changes in the HTML/CSS or browser inspector. What could be wrong here?

And what if I wanted to make the style only at a certain screen size, like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){#header.header-front-page{background-size:100!important;}}
```

How would I go about doing that with PHP/Javascript?
This also doesn't work.

```
<?php
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_front_page ()) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1'>
        if (matchMedia("(max-width: 760)").matches) { 
            // the viewport is at most 760 pixels wide 
            $('#header.header-front-page').css('background-size', '100%!important')
        }
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

EDIT:
the following are the web inspector details:
so these are the relevant HTML styles in the "Elements" tab of inspector in Chrome:

```
<style type="text/css" id="illdy-about-section-css">#header.header-front-page {background-image: url(image.png) !important;}
#header.header-front-page {background-position-y: center;}
#header.header-front-page {background-position-x: center;}
#header.header-front-page {background-size: auto !important;}
#header.header-front-page {background-attachment: scroll !important;}
</style>
```

and the actual element HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="header-front-page" style="background-image: url(https://image.png);
background-attachment: fixed;" aria-hidden="false">
</header>
```

and this in the "Styles" inspector:

[image: Styles]

Comment: 1st: injecting inline CSS / JS into WP template files isn't the WordPress way. They should be enqueued using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) or the like. 2nd: WordPress uses jQuery in noConflict mode, so you'll need to replace the `$` with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

why you prefer use javascript instead off css it self?
javascript will overwrite the css rules if you put in wrong ways.

please provide me the web inspect (if you use chrome or firefox). sometimes, css will not work if **precedence not qualified**
reff: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

if you cant provide the web inspect, would you like to provide me the url instead?

Comment: I'm not using CSS itself because the site uses inline (HTML <style>) CSS with !important, which I believe holds the highest importance. I tried using CSS and adding it, but it didn't work.

I am going to add web inspect details to the original post. Thank you!